# Why am I not seeing an output when I synthesize?

Tags: vhdl

I have been working on a lab assignment that is practically complete, but am running into an issue where I am not seeing an output when synthesizing.  I have 7 blocks, that when tested individually display the correct output.  How is it that I wouldn't get any output at all when using the top module and test bench files?  Below is my top module, followed by my test bench as I suspect the problem may be there.  I've looked it over and can't pinpoint anything I may have done wrong.  Any help would be appreciated.

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;

entity top_module is port(
    x,y : in std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
    opcode : in std_logic_vector(2 downto 0);
    z : out std_logic_vector(7 downto 0)
    );
end top_module;

architecture behavior of top_module is

signal bwAnd, bwOr, bwXor, add, subtract, bwComplement, mux_in1, mux_in2, mux_in3, mux_in4, mux_in5, mux_in6 : std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);


component BW_And is port(
    x,y : in std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
    z1 : out std_logic_vector(7 downto 0)
    );
end component;

component BW_Rr is port(
    x,y : in std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
    z2 : out std_logic_vector(7 downto 0)
    );
end component;

component BW_Xor is port(
    x,y : in std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
    z3 : out std_logic_vector(7 downto 0)
    );
end component;

component full_adder_8 is port(
    x,y : in std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
    cin : in std_logic_vector(7 downto 0) := "00000000";
    sum, cout: out std_logic_vector(7 downto 0)
    );
end component;

component full_subtractor_8 is port(
    x,y : in std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
    cin : in std_logic_vector(7 downto 0) := "11111111";
difference, cout: out std_logic_vector(7 downto 0)
    );
end component;

component Complement is port(
    x : in std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
    z4 : out std_logic_vector(7 downto 0)
    );
end component;

component mux is port(
    z1,z2,z3,sum,difference,z4 : in std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
    opcode : in std_logic_vector(2 downto 0);
    mux_out : out std_logic_vector(7 downto 0)
    );
end component;

begin

--instantiating components and mapping ports

c0: BW_And port map(x => x, y => y, z1 => bwAnd);

c1: BW_Or port map(x => x, y => y, z2 => bwOr);

c2: BW_Xor port map(x => x, y => y, z3 => bwXor);

c3: full_adder_8 port map(x => x, y => y, sum => add);

c4: full_subtractor_8 port map(x => x, y => y, difference => subtract);

c5: Complement port map(x => x, z4 => bwComplement);

c6: mux port map(z1 => mux_in1, z2 => mux_in2, z3 => mux_in3, sum => mux_in4, difference => mux_in5, z4 =>mux_in6, opcode => opcode, mux_out => z);

end behavior;
```

Test Bench:

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;

entity Lab4 is
end Lab4;

architecture behavior of Lab4 is

component top_module is port(
    x,y : in std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
    opcode : in std_logic_vector(2 downto 0);
    z : out std_logic_vector(7 downto 0)
    );
end component;

signal test_x : std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
signal test_y : std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
signal test_opcode : std_logic_vector(2 downto 0) := "000";
signal test_z : std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);

begin

    uut: top_module port map (x => test_x, y => test_y, opcode => test_opcode, z => test_z);

sim_proc : process
begin

    test_x <= "00010100"; test_y <= "11001111"; test_opcode <= "000";
    wait for 100 ns;
    test_x <= "00010100"; test_y <= "11001111"; test_opcode <= "001";
    wait for 100 ns;
    test_x <= "00010100"; test_y <= "11001111"; test_opcode <= "010";
    wait for 100 ns;
    test_x <= "00010100"; test_y <= "11001111"; test_opcode <= "011";
    wait for 100 ns;
    test_x <= "00010100"; test_y <= "11001111"; test_opcode <= "100";
    wait for 100 ns;
    test_x <= "00010100"; test_y <= "11001111"; test_opcode <= "101";

end process;
end behavior;
```

Entities for each component:

```
entity BW_And is port(
    x,y : in std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
    z1 : out std_logic_vector(7 downto 0)
    );
end BW_And;

entity BW_Or is port(
    x,y : in std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
    z2 : out std_logic_vector(7 downto 0)
    );
end BW_Or;

entity BW_Xor is port(
    x,y : in std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
    z3 : out std_logic_vector(7 downto 0)
    );
end BW_Xor;

entity full_adder_8 is port(
    x,y : in std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
    cin : in std_logic_vector(7 downto 0) := "00000000";
    sum, cout: out std_logic_vector(7 downto 0)
    );
end full_adder_8;

entity full_subtractor_8 is port(
    x,y : in std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
    cin : in std_logic_vector(7 downto 0) := "11111111";
    difference, cout: out std_logic_vector(7 downto 0)
    );
end full_subtractor_8;

entity Complement is port(
    x : in std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
    z4 : out std_logic_vector(7 downto 0)
    );
end Complement;

entity mux is port(
    z1,z2,z3,sum,difference,z4 : in std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
    opcode : in std_logic_vector(2 downto 0);
    mux_out : out std_logic_vector(7 downto 0)
    );
end mux;
```

Comment: Where are the entities corresponding to your 7 components?

Comment: @MatthewTaylor The entities are in separate files.  For example:  bw_and.vhd, bw_or.vhd, etc are defined separately.  They include entity and architecture.

Comment: The output `z` is driven from `mux`, but that entity is not included as Matthew points out, so it is not possible to determine what is wrong with the output.

Comment: Btw. please create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), since doing so may reveal the problem, and will make it easier for others to help.

Comment: @MortenZilmer I have added the entities for all of the components as requested.

Answer (score -1):

I realized where my problem was after all.  The issue was with my mux file.  In my process, I only passed "opcode" neglecting to pass in all of the inputs.

Before:

```
process (opcode)
    .
    .
    .
end process;
```

After:

```
process (z1,z2,z3,sum,difference,z4,opcode)
    .
    .
    .
end process;
```

Comment: You don't pass inputs to processes. That is a process sensitivity list.  See IEEE Std 1076-2008 11.3 Process statement used as a sensitivity list for the implicit wait statement as a last statement in the process. Sensitivity lists generally have no bearing on synthesis. Please consider providing your question with a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).